# Calculate derivate of spatial measurements

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spatial

I have a set of spatial distributed measurements.
For each point `p1 = [x1,y1,z1]` there is a measurement `v1` which is a scalar. (e.g. Temperature measurements under water.)
Lets assume these measurements are on a regular grid.
I would like to find out where is the most variation in this distribution.
That means in what positions is the most change of temperature.
I think this corresponds to the spatial derivation of temperature.
Can somebody give me an advice how to proceed?
What are methodologies to archive this?
I tried to implement it with `np.gradient()` but i fail at interpreting the result...

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely not an optimized code, but here is what I came up with, at least to explain how it works.

```py
grid = [[[1, 2], [2, 3]], [[8, 5], [4, 1000]]]

def get_greatest_diff(g, x, y, z):
    value = g[x][y][z]
    try:
        diff_x = abs(value-g[x+1][y][z])
    except IndexError:
        diff_x = -1
    try:
        diff_y= abs(value-g[x][y+1][z])
    except IndexError:
        diff_y = -1
    try:
        diff_z = abs(value-g[x][y][z+1])
    except IndexError:
        diff_z = -1
    if diff_x>=diff_y and diff_x>=diff_z:
        return diff_x, [x+1, y, z]
    if diff_y>diff_x and diff_y>=diff_z:
        return diff_y, [x, y+1, z]
    return diff_z, [x, y, z+1]

greatest_diff = 0
greatest_diff_pos0 = []
greatest_diff_pos1 = []
for x in range(len(grid)):
    for y in range(len(grid[x])):
        for z in range(len(grid[x][y])):
            diff, coords = get_greatest_diff(grid, x, y, z)
            if diff > greatest_diff:
                greatest_diff = diff
                greatest_diff_pos0 = [x, y, z]
                greatest_diff_pos1 = coords
print(greatest_diff, greatest_diff_pos0, greatest_diff_pos1)
```

The `try:...except:...` are here to handle the edge conditions. (That's dirty but that's quick!)

For each cell, you will look at the three neighbours `x+1` or `y+1` or `z+1` and you compute the difference with their values. You keep the largest difference in the neighborhood and you return it. (That is the explanation of `get_greatest_diff`)

In the main loop, you check if the difference in this neighborhood is the greatest of all, if so, store the difference, and the two cells in question.

Finally, return the greatest difference and the cells in question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `numpy` solution that returns the indices in an `ndarray` that has the biggest total differences with its neighbors.
Say the input array is `X` and it is `2D`. I will create `D` where `D[i,j] = |X[i, j]-X[i-1, j]|+|X[i,j]-X[i, j-1]|`. And return the indices of `D` which give the largest value in `D`.

```
def greatest_diff(X):
    
    ndim = X.ndim
    Ds = [np.abs(np.diff(X, axis = i, prepend=0)) for i in range(ndim)]
    D = sum(Ds)
    return np.unravel_index(D.argmax(), D.shape)

X = np.zeros((5,5))
X[2,2] = 1
greatest_diff(X)
# returns (2, 2)

X = np.zeros((5,10,9))
X[2,2,7] = -1
greatest_diff(X)
# returns (2, 2, 7)
```

Another solution might be calculating the difference between `X[i, j]` and `sum(X[k, l])` where `k,l` are the neighbors of `i, j`. You can achieve this by applying a gaussian filter to the `X` say `gX` then taking the squared differences: `(X-gX)^2`.

```
def greatest_diff_gaussian(X, sigma = 1):
    from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
    gX = gaussian_filter(X, sigma)
    dgX = np.power(X - gX, 2)
    return np.unravel_index(dgX.argmax(), dgX.shape)
```